# Adding timestamp column to pre-existing csv

Tags: php, csv

So I've got a CSV file with rows that look like this:

> 126404    "560-00877" "CENTER CAP,GRADE A,GRAY,"  877 2   34.29   0

I'd like to add a time stamp column so they look like this:

> 126404 "560-00877" "CENTER CAP,GRADE A,GRAY," 877 2 34.29 0 2005-04-06

Is there a simple(r) php method of opening the CSV file and appending a timestamp to each row?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could read each line of the file into an array, and append the time stamp to each line when you write it back:

```
$filename="/path/to/file.txt";

// Backup
if(!copy($filename, 'backup.txt')){
    die('Failed to backup!');
}

// Store file contents in array
$arrFile = file($filename);

// Open file for output
if(($fp = fopen($filename,'w')) === FALSE){
    die('Failed to open!');
}

// Write contents, inserting $data as second line
$currentLine = 0;
$cntFile = count($arrFile);
while( $currentLine <= $cntFile ){
    fwrite($fp, $arrFile[$currentLine].",".date('y-m-d').",\n");
    $currentLine++;
}

// Delete backup
unlink('backup.txt');
```

Just modify the line with `date('Y-M-D')` to fit your needs.

Comment: Hmmm... it seems to be writing to the file, but does not append anything (the date). Any ideas?

Comment: Probably a typo here with 'backup.xml'... Also, you read the whole file into memory which can be too long for PHP default memory limits. Probably skipped for simplicity, so just letting the poster know.

Comment: No, I don't think that the backup.xml typo was the problem, but I corrected it anyway. Can you show us the whole line with date? Also, try `date('y-m-d', $time)` for good measure.

Answer (score 0):

this one?

```
$data = file("file.csv",FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$fp = fopen("file_new.csv","w");
foreach((array)$data as $val) {
   fwrite($fp,$val." ".$timestamp."\r\n");   // build the $timestamp   
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: With default PHP limitations on memory it's easy to run out of it when reading a whole file at once. You probably have just skipped that for simplicity, so just letting the question poster know.

Comment: yes, the user just asked for a simple method, so i did just that.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get with standard functions is using fgetcsv/fputcsv which do the parsing/escaping job for you:

```
$hSrc = fopen('path/to/file.csv', 'o');
if ($hSrc === false) {
    throw new Exception('Cannot open source file for reading!');
}

$hDest = fopen('path/to/new.csv', 'w');
if ($hDest === false) {
    throw new Exception('Cannot open destination file for writing!');
}

$timestamp = date('Y-m-d');

// reading source file into an array line by line
$buffer = 1000; // should be enough to accommodate the longest row
while (($row = fgetcsv($hSrc, $buffer, ' ')) !== false) {
    $data['timestamp'] = $timestamp;

    // writing that modified row into a new file
    if (fputcsv($hDest, $data, ' ') === false) {
        throw new Exception('Failed to write a CSV row!');
    }
}

fclose($hDest);
fclose($hSrc);
```

Comment: $buffer = 1000; // should be enough to accommodate the longest row. You'll never know actually in my opinion..

Comment: Correct, that's my fault given I tried to provide "safe" code. That parameter is optional to speed the processing up, if left with default 0 value there will be no limit (apart from natural limitations).

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
<?php
$file_path = "yourfile.txt";
$file = file($file_path, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
foreach ($file as $line => $content)
{
    $file[$line] = $content." ".date('Y-m-d');
}
$file = implode("\n",$file);
file_put_contents($file_path, $file);
?>
```